# Consuming Binance API

Tags: api, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, binance, binance-smart-chain

My team and I are building a webapp that can consume data from Binance API, but their documentation is quite complicated to understand. I need someone to show me how to:

- obtain the live feeds of prices of crypto assets
- seamless communication between pur wallet on binance protocol and other users on our website
- automated account balance for our users, based on live feeds from binance restful api.
- and much more.

I'll be glad for any useful help, thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question seems to be too broad and needs more focus to be ontopic. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and other articles in the help section.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python there are plenty of Binance API wrappers that you can make use of.
They have almost all the functionalities available in binanca official API docs, in a user-friendly manner.

For example, you can check [python-binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a start.